# Categories variable pair not backspacing at all

Tags: categories, list

I am using the following code to display an inline list of regions from a categories list for a product entry. The backspace isn't working at all, no matter how I change my code around. I will post a couple of the combinations I tried. Any ideas?

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Region: 
    {categories show_group="9" style="linear" backspace="7"}
        <a href="{path=/products}">{category_name}</a>,&nbsp;
    {/categories}
    </p></li>
</ul>
```

as well as

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Region: 
    {categories show_group="9" style="linear" backspace="7"}
        <a href="{path=/products}">{category_name},&nbsp;</a>
    {/categories}
    </p></li>
</ul>
```

and this one with a , and regular space afterwards

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Region: 
    {categories show_group="9" style="linear" backspace="2"}
        <a href="{path=/products}">{category_name}</a>, 
    {/categories}
    </p></li>
</ul>
```

I've read a few posts on the ellislabs forums related to this...which is why I have a few combinations, but nothing is working. I am using EE 2.6.1.

Comment: The backspace count includes whitespace, have you accounted for that?

Comment: Kevin is right, the spaces and line returns count. Move the closing categories tag just after that anchor and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out whitespace and placement of the closing categories tag was the issue. I moved the whole tag group onto 1 line in my template, and moved the , and closing categories tag outside of the closing `</a>` tag. Thanks Kevin and Nuno! I added a span so I could color the commas the same as the links.

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Region: 
        <span>{categories show_group="9" backspace="2"}<a href="{path=/products}">{category_name}</a>, {/categories}</span>
    </p></li>
</ul>
```